# Building a menu navigation but failing on the looping through json

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am building a menu navigation system using slicnav.  I have a list of resident incidents and I am building the system by date. I want a year then month then day expandable navigation then a list of incidents by day.

Here is Some of the json data:

```
{
    "incidents" : [{
            "securityincidentid" : 2928,
            "incyear" : 2019,
            "incyearmonth" : "2019-4",
            "incyearmonthday" : "2019-4-15",
            "monthname" : "April",
            "incday" : 15,
            "incidentdatetime" : "2019-04-15 17:15:00.000",
            "resemployees" : "5:15PM "
        }, {
            "securityincidentid" : 2930,
            "incyear" : 2019,
            "incyearmonth" : "2019-4",
            "incyearmonthday" : "2019-4-15",
            "monthname" : "April",
            "incday" : 15,
            "incidentdatetime" : "2019-04-15 14:13:00.000",
            "resemployees" : "2:13PM"
        }, {
            "securityincidentid" : 2933,
            "incyear" : 2019,
            "incyearmonth" : "2019-4",
            "incyearmonthday" : "2019-4-15",
            "monthname" : "April",
            "incday" : 15,
            "incidentdatetime" : "2019-04-15 14:00:00.000",
            "resemployees" : "2:00PM "
        }, {
            "securityincidentid" : 2927,
            "incyear" : 2019,
            "incyearmonth" : "2019-4",
            "incyearmonthday" : "2019-4-15",
            "monthname" : "April",
            "incday" : 15,
            "incidentdatetime" : "2019-04-15 14:00:00.000",
            "resemployees" : "2:00PM "
        }, {
            "securityincidentid" : 2929,
            "incyear" : 2019,
            "incyearmonth" : "2019-4",
            "incyearmonthday" : "2019-4-15",
            "monthname" : "April",
            "incday" : 15,
            "incidentdatetime" : "2019-04-15 13:55:00.000",
            "resemployees" : "1:55PM"
        }, {
            "securityincidentid" : 2931,
            "incyear" : 2019,
            "incyearmonth" : "2019-4",
            "incyearmonthday" : "2019-4-14",
            "monthname" : "April",
            "incday" : 14,
            "incidentdatetime" : "2019-04-14 09:52:00.000",
            "resemployees" : "9:52AM"
        }]}
```

Here is the jquery code to build the menu

```
var
                incyear="",
                incyearmonth="",
                incyearmonthday="";        
            $.each(navdata.incidents,function(key,value){
                if(incyear!==value.incyear){
                    $securityincidenul.append(
                        $('<li>').prop({id:value.incyear+"-fd"}).text(value.incyear).append(
                            $('<ul>').prop({id:value.incyear+"-fd-ul"}).append(
                                $('<li>').prop({id:value.incyearmonth+"-fd"}).text(value.monthname).append(
                                    $('<ul>').prop({id:value.incyearmonth+"-fd-ul"}).append(
                                        $('<li>').prop({id:value.incyearmonthday+"-fd"}).text(value.incday).append(
                                            $('<ul>').prop({id:value.incyearmonthday+"-fd-ul"}).append(
                                                    $('<li>').prop({id:value.securityincidentid}).append(
                                                        $('<a>').prop({href:"#"}).click(function(){
                                                            createsecincidentform(value.securityincidentid)
                                                        }).text(value.resemployees)
                                                    )
                                            )
                                        ) 
                                    )    
                                )
                            )
                        )
                    )   
                }else if(incyearmonth!==value.incyearmonth){
                    $("#"+incyear+"-fd-ul").append(
                        $('<li>').prop({id:value.incyearmonth+"-fd"}).text(value.monthname).append(
                            $('<ul>').prop({id:value.incyearmonth+"-fd-ul"}).append(
                                $('<li>').prop({id:value.incyearmonthday+"-fd"}).text(value.incday).append(
                                    $('<ul>').prop({id:value.incyearmonthday+"-fd-ul"}).append(
                                            $('<li>').prop({id:value.securityincidentid}).append(
                                                $('<a>').prop({href:"#"}).click(function(){
                                                            createsecincidentform(value.securityincidentid)
                                                        }).text(value.resemployees)
                                            )
                                    )
                                ) 
                            )    
                        )    
                    )  
                }else if(incyearmonthday!==value.incyearmonthday){
                    $("#"+value.incyearmonth+"-fd-ul").append(
                            $('<li>').prop({id:value.incyearmonthday+"-fd"}).text(value.incday).append(
                                $('<ul>').prop({id:value.incyearmonthday+"-fd-ul"}).append(
                                    $('<li>').prop({id:value.securityincidentid}).append(
                                        $('<a>').prop({href:"#"}).click(function(){
                                            createsecincidentform(value.securityincidentid)
                                        }).text(value.resemployees)
                                    )
                                )   
                            )   
                        )
                }else if(incyearmonthday===value.incyearmonthday){
                    $("#"+value.inceyearmonthday+"-fd-ul").append(
                        $('<li>').prop({id:value.securityincidentid}).append(
                            $('<a>').prop({href:"#"}).click(function(){
                                createsecincidentform(value.securityincidentid)
                            }).text(value.resemployees)
                        )
                    )    
                } 
                incyear=value.incyear;
                incyearmonth=value.incyearmonth; 
                incyearmonthday=value.incyearmonthday;    
            })
```

As you can see I have 4 records for 4/15/2019 and then one for 4/14/2019.  It is only showing the first record for each day and not the subsequent records.   Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure your JSON is formatted correctly? I see that it starts at `{ "incidents" :` but in the end of it `"9:52AM" }]` its missing the closing bracket `}`

Comment: This code style is terrible (code nesting) - sorry I had to. There is no much performance gain if you don't use variables. In fact you can gain - I see repeating fragments of code.

Comment: I do use variables. I use a variable for the main ul to build the navigation. And the json is formatted correctly.  I just clipped out some of the data as an example.  My bad.

Comment: Zydnar what would you suggest